# How to repeat chapter numbers

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, counters, bookmarks

I'm writing my Ph.D. thesis, and I have to write the Introduction both in English and in Spanish. Since the content is the same, I want to repeat the number of this first chapter:

> 1. Introducción.
> 2. Introduction.
> 3. Next Chapter, etc.

If I simply reset the counter by calling `\setcounter{chapter}{0}` I obtain the desired numbering, but the table of contents that appears in the left margin of pdf viewers looks odd:

All the chapters are nested into the first one. On the other hand, the links in the `\tableofcontents` page don't behave properly, i.e. if I click on the link corresponding to the spanish introduction, I'm sent to the english (the last) one.

I guess I should create a special kind of chapter for the spanish introduction in order to obtain a repeated number that do not interfere with the `\tableofcontents` or associate a new counter to `\chapter` in order to separate the two versions. Any help?

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using? What about the [`bookmark` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark)...are you using that or *only* [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)? What other sectional packages are you using to format your document. These are all important things that could affect a possible solution. Ideally we'd like to see a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that highlights and reproduces your problem. It'll make solution come your way much easier, and help the community work on your problem much faster.

Comment: With the `book` class your little hack works perfectly...

Comment: I wasn't using the bookmark package: that solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [`bookmark` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) to see whether this fixes your problems. `bookmark` implements bookmarks in documents in a more modern (less restrictive) way, and only requires a single compile. [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) requires at least two compiles (assuming something changes in the ToC), since it uses auxiliary files during compiles to assemble the bookmarks.

---

If you're only using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), the following would correct the hyperlinks and is *cheapest*:

- Add `\renewcommand{\theHchapter}{S\arabic{chapter}}` *before* your Spanish chapter `\chapter{Introducción}`; and
- `\renewcommand{\theHchapter}{\arabic{chapter}}` *after* the Spanish chapter

`\theHchapter` is used as an anchor for the hyperlink to a chapter, and depends on the chapter number. If you reset the chapter number, then the hyperlink reference will be ambiguous, causing a jump to the same location. The above fixes that temporarily by prepending `S` to the Spanish chapter anchor, and the subsequently removing it.

Perhaps a more generic way of approaching this would be to define a macro that you can switch between, allowing you to insert similar-numbered chapters as needed. The following MWE allows for that:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/inputenc
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\newcommand{\chaptype}{}
\newcommand{\chaptertype}[1]{\renewcommand{\chaptype}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\theHchapter}{\chaptype\arabic{chapter}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chaptertype{Spanish}
\chapter{Introducción}

\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\chaptertype{}
\chapter{Introduction}

\chapter{Next Chapter}
\end{document}
```

`\chaptertype{<stuff>}` is the user-level interface which updates `\chaptype` to be `<stuff>`. This is then used as a prefix for the `hyperref` anchor in `\theHchapter`. You can switch back to the regular "prefix" using `\chaptertype{}`.

---

The motivation behind this solution stems from the [`hyperref` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html) (specifically section [**3.2 Options for destination names**](http://ctan.cms.math.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html#x1-60003.2)):

> It is very important that the destination names are unique, because two destinations must not share the same name. The counter value `\the<counter>` is not always unique for the counter. For example, table and figures can be numbered inside the chapter without having the chapter number in their number. Therefore `hyperref` has introduced `\theH<counter>` that allows a unique counter value without messing up with the appearance of the counter number. For example, the number of the second table in the third chapter might be printed as `2`, the result of `\thetable`. But the destination name `table.2.4` is unique because it has used `\theHtable` that gives `2.4` in this case.

Comment: Thanks! As I said above, the inclusion of the bookmark package solve the problem. But the modification on \theHchapter also works (without the bookmark package).

Comment: @I.O.: If this solved your problem, perhaps consider accepting it as such. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://goo.gl/hzFkJ)

Answer (score 1):

You can exploit the fact that you're going to write your *Introducción* in Spanish, so inside an environment.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,english]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref,bookmark}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\begin{otherlanguage}{spanish}
\renewcommand{\theHchapter}{SpanishIntro} % keep bookmark quiet
\chapter{Introducción}

Introducción in Español.

\end{otherlanguage}

\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}

\chapter{Introduction}

The introduction in English

\chapter{Next Chapter}
\end{document}
```

If you still want “Chapter 1” instead of “Capítulo 1”, then use `otherlanguage*` in place of `otherlanguage`.